# SKNodes in SKScene moving in the wrong direction

Tags: ios, swift, tiled, jstilemap

I am implementing a one dimension movement along the x axis.

The objects are moving but they are in the wrong directions

Code for moving the scene

```
self.obstacles.position.x -= speed // obstacles = objects
self.map.position.x -= speed // map is the scene
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I forgot to attach my nodes to the worldCamera node.